# Why does a signed certificate give me a handshake failure using Java?

Tags: java, ssl, self-signed

I am accessing a web service.  When I go to the web service's URL in my browser, the certificate is signed and automatically is accepted.

What I don't understand is that when I use Java to access the web service I get something along the lines of:

> javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

I would imagine this means that the certificate is not signed, but it is.

Doesn't `com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl` go to the certificate authority automatically and check if the certificate is signed?  If not, is there something I need to set up in addition in order to do this?

Comment: Maybe this post will help you:

http://stackoverflow.com/a/9816228/190596

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is more checking than just the signature. The certificate authority that produced the signature must be validated, among other things. Java's list of trusted certificate authorities is different than your browser's. You may need to download the CA cert with your browser and install it with Java's keytool.

Comment: So there are no CA authorities used by Java by default?  I thought the root certificates for security authorities are an Operating System wide property?

Comment: There is a list in Java by default. But it is separate from the one your browser uses.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the web server or the URL you are connecting to does not have a valid certificate from an authorized CA.To solve see this alternative [solution](http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=210).

Comment: Not necessarily - the certificate's CA may just not be in the JRE's list. This can happen with an old JRE or a new CA.